# How would I stop the click method from working more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click method on a button + link that animates stuff as a result of the click. However, I want it so that it only works once. I managed to disable the button after it's clicked, so that's good. But I tried `.disabled = true` on the link and it didn't work. Is there some way I could prevent it from being clicked more than once?

JS

```
$('#frontbutton, #loginlink').on('click', function(){
    $('.popup').hide();
    usernameInput.val('');
    emailInput.val('');
    passwordInput.val('');
    confirmInput.val('');
    $('.intro').animate({opacity: '0.5'}, 1000).delay(800).animate({
        left: "+=300px"
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.formholder').show()}, 2000);
    $('.toppic').animate({opacity: '0.5'}, 1000).delay(800).animate({
        top: "+=300px"
    });
    document.getElementById('frontbutton').disabled = true;
});
```

Comment: You can use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

Comment: count the clicks and store it in an object. on click check the objects value if clickTrack > 1 return false else return (your function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#frontbutton, #loginlink').one('click', function(){
```

`.one()` behaves like `.on()`, but the handler unbinds itself once it has been called.

Answer (score 1):

Try `one('click',function(){...` instead of `on('click',function(){...`.  The event will only run once per element.
[Here's the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Answer (score 1):

With jquery you can turn the event off this way

```
 $('#frontbutton, #loginlink').on('click.myEventNamespace',function(){
       //Run my code
       $('#frontbutton, #loginlink').off('click.myEventNamespace');
 });
```

You can also do this inside your event.  Thought it may be worth knowing for when you don't use jQuery

```
 this.removeEventListener('click',arguments.callee,false);
```